# Mongodb use schildscheme in scheme itself

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Image that I have the following MongoDB model in Mongoose:

```
const stats = new mongoose.Schema({
    startDate: Date,
    endDate: Date
    totals: {
        revenue: Number,
        tax: Number,
        profit: Number
    }
})
```

Now I want to reuse this schema in the schema itself. Each document contains the totals of a whole month, and for each separated day. So the complete model would be something like this:

```
const model = new mongoose.Schema({
    stats,
    days: [{stats}]
})
```

This is the code which I currently have, but when I try to create a new document in this model, there is nothing saved except for a empty array at `days`.

So it looks like that the `stats` property is not recognized as an schema (probably due to the missing name/key). How can I archive something like this?

### Edit 1:

Fixed 1 fault in the model. The model is now looking like this:

```
const model = new mongoose.Schema({
    stats,
    days: [stats]
})
```

Now the model is created with data in `days[]` but the model itself is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining it as:

```
const model = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...stats.obj,
    days: [{stats:{ type: stats}}]
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that was 1 fault, the array was defined the wrong way. It's now `days: [stats]`. Now the days[] is filling correctly but the main properties are still empty. I have edited my question with the updated model based on this suggestion

Comment: Can you send the way you are filling in the data?

Comment: I guess you want the stats fields in the root of your new schema. if so, you can do it by `...stats.obj`